# fix background image on android

Tags: android, image, layout, background-image, android-screen-support

How can I use an image background for all android device without stretch it?

I've tried on Galaxy S3, S4 and Tab3 but the image is deformed. 
 have you any suggestions?

This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background_carrying_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/c"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Set background image to your Parent layout. You can use different screen resolution images in different drawable folders.

Comment: what solution do you use now? can you give us the code?

Comment: I've added the code. I have 5 folders (drawable-ldpi...drawable-xxhdpi) and a special layout folder for tablets 7'' (layout-sw600dp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the scale type :

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```